# How to transformation 'string' to 'variable' Python 2.7?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, variables

i need help, please. The code is more big but i show you the idea with a example.
How to transformation 'string union' to 'variable union'

Thanks

```
dictionary1    = {'a':1,'b':2}
p1              = 'dictionary'
p2              = 1
union           = p1+str(p2)
vars()[union]   = union
for key,value in union.items():
    print key,value
```

Comment: sorry, this is the code

Comment: dictionary1    = {'a':1,'b':2}
p1              = 'dictionary'
p2              = 1
union           = p1+str(p2)
for key,value in union.items():
    print key,value

Comment: So what would you want to do? The `vars()[union] = union` bit is nonsensical (what that line does here is sort of equivalent to `dictionary1 = 'dictionary1'` which is fairly pointless, and outside of global scope, not supported).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal is to be able to access a variable with a dynamic name, the only solution that works at global, nested and local scope without a lot of fallback code (to handle both local and globally scoped names) is to use `eval`:

```
dictionary1 = {'a':1,'b':2}
p1 = 'dictionary'
p2 = 1
union = p1+str(p2)
for key, value in eval(union).items():
    print key, value
```

All `eval(union)` does is execute the contents of the string referenced by `union` as if it were a Python expression; as it happens, the name of a variable is a perfectly legal Python expression, so it's legal, if not super-safe, to use `eval` to perform the lookup for you.

If the variable is known to be in local or global scope already, you could do:

```
for key, value in locals()[union].items():

for key, value in globals()[union].items():
```

which is safer (in that it can't execute arbitrary code like `eval` can), but won't dynamically check local, nested and global scopes (any such checks would have to be performed manually, and nested scope would be *ugly*).

Note that in general, this is a *bad* idea. If you need to access variables by name, just make a dictionary mapping names (as strings) to the values you care about. Then you can use code like this safely, without the `eval` security/stability risks:

```
mydicts = {'dictionary1': {'a':1,'b':2}}
p1 = 'dictionary'
p2 = 1
union = p1+str(p2)
# If union is not a string in the dictionary, this will raise KeyError,
# but can't execute arbitrary code
for key, value in mydicts[union].items():
    print key, value
```

Comment: But the OP is trying to _set_ variables by name (that `vars()[union] = …`). You can't do that with `eval`, because assignment isn't an expression (at least not until 3.8…). You _could_ do it with `exec`, but then you need all the same fallback code for locals that you were trying to avoid.

Comment: `globals().setdefault(union, eval(union))` will work. Using `eval('dictionary1')` just returns the object pointed to by `dictionary1`, so in your answer it doesn't actually define anything in the global scope (nor the local, but it's presumably already there). If this code is being executed in a loop, the variable name of the dictionary would presumably be the same every pass, so OP could do `globals().setdefault(union, dictionary1)` with no `eval`.

Comment: @abarnert: You could do it with `eval`+`compile`. `eval` only evaluates string expressions, but a statement, including assignment, can be compiled using `compile` in `'single'` mode, then immediately passed to `eval`. I tend to use `eval`+`compile` in general, because much of the code I write has to be source compatible with Py2 and Py3, and `eval`+`compile` is the only general dynamic code execution technique that works reliably on both.

Comment: @ZachGates: The OP seemed to be asking to dynamically load a variable, not set it (`dictionary1` already existed, they just wanted to load it dynamically as far as I can tell), so `eval` was sufficient. Granted, `vars()[union] = union` could be a misguided attempt at any number of things, but I interpreted it as a misguided attempt to dynamically load `dictionary1`; if they wanted to set `union` to *be* `dictionary1`, then `union = eval('dictionary1')` would work just fine.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `eval` plus `compile` is even worse than `exec` for namespaces—it will always do a `STORE_NAME` even when there's a local..

Comment: @abarnert: [Dynamically updating `locals` is illegal anyway](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars): "Note, the locals dictionary is only useful for reads since updates to the locals dictionary are ignored." That's a fundamental aspect of CPython's design; the array of locals is baked in at function compile time, and can't be expanded. `locals()`/`vars()` is just making a `dict` that maps the known names to values, but it's not able to create new, true locals.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Sure, but do you want code that will silently do the wrong thing and overwrite a global when called at local scope, instead of either raising an exception or harmlessly but uselessly modifying locals?

Comment: @abarnert: Well, as I noted, my initial suggestion was solely to read the variable, not set it. That's legal and safe. You were the one suggesting that `vars()[union] = …` was an attempt to set a variable (it's a nonsensical line of code; I have no idea what they thought it was doing). I only pointed out `eval`+`compile` because you claimed `eval` couldn't do it (and `exec` could) when `eval` is perfectly capable of doing so. Whether it's *sane* to do so is a wholly different matter. :-)